# Cluster network name blank in SQL cluster node configuration (setup exit with “Error code 0x84C00001”)

Tags: sql, failovercluster

I created 2 nodes fail over Microsoft cluster Windows 2016. On the node 1 an SQL 2014 server clustered has been installed, the new role is working and is online in the cluster management console.
Now i should add the node 2 to the the SQL Server cluster for the role to be switched on the node 2, but installing SQL 2014 on the node 2 i come across this issue:

[Cluster network name is blank.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VF9L.png)

Since it is not possible to insert the cluster network name manually, i clicked on "next":

[The IP address for the SQL cluster role is blank too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Xlb.png)

Here it is possible to insert manually the IP address of the SQL cluster role and that's what i did, but clicking on "next" setup throw an exception exiting with: "The sql server failover cluster instance name " could not be found as a cluster resource" (Error code 0x84C00001).

I googled for a few hours searching for a solution, but without success.

Since the Cluster Network name should be not blank (and thats' the issue i suppose) someone can help me in understanding how to solve the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and checked again the cluster.log file, where I found following entries:

```
r <SQL Server (INSTANCENAME)>: [sqsrvres] Dependency expression for resource 'INSTANCENAME' is '([af9669ae-e2b9-4548-994f-172d5ab167ed])'
000022b0.00000958::2021/04/05-16:51:40.485 ERR [RES] SQL Server <SQL Server (INSTANCENAME)>: [sqsrvres] Unable to open the SQL Server instance registry of 'Cluster' with error: 2. Please contact customer support
000022b0.00002fc0::2021/04/05-16:51:40.486 ERR   [RES] SQL Server <SQL Server (INSTANCENAME)>: [sqsrvres] GetRegKeyAccessMask: Could not get registry access mask for registry key Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.INSTANCENAME\Cluster (status 2)).
000022b0.00002fc0::2021/04/05-16:51:40.486 ERR   [RES] SQL Server <SQL Server (INSTANCENAME)>: [sqsrvres] Worker Thread (1C8ECDE0): Failed to retrieve the SQL Server cluster registry key (last error = 2).
000022b0.00000958::2021/04/05-16:51:40.486 ERR   [RES] SQL Server <SQL Server (INSTANCENAME)>: [sqsrvres] SQL Cluster shared data upgrade failed with error 0 (worker retval = 2). Please contact customer support
000022b0.00000958::2021/04/05-16:51:40.486 ERR   [RES] SQL Server <SQL Server (INSTANCENAME)>: [sqsrvres] Failed to prepare environment for online. See previous message for detail. Please contact customer support
000022b0.00000958::2021/04/05-16:51:40.486 INFO  [RES] SQL Server <SQL Server (INSTANCENAME)>: [sqsrvres] SQL Server resource state is changed from 'ClusterResourceOnlinePending' to 'ClusterResourceFailed'
000022b0.00000958::2021/04/05-16:51:40.486 WARN  [RHS] Online for resource SQL Server (INSTANCENAME) failed.
```

For some reason the SQL uninstall node setup had erroneously deleted some registry keys from path Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.INSTANCENAME\Cluster.

When i recreated them by using a healthy instance as reference, I was able to run the SQL Server repair wizard successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked my cluster.log file, but i can't find any error about registry access; on the healthy node (node 1) i checked the registry key Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.INSTANCENAME, but i can't find the "Cluster" key (maybe for my different version of SQL). The only key i see that have a similar name is "ClusterState". On the node where i get the issue (node 2), the registry key MSSQL12.INSTANCENAME is totally missing. I wish to be able to solve this issue one day...

Comment: Hello, check the extra step I took which is documented in the following blog post: https://stefanos.cloud/blog/kb/unexpected-errors-when-removing-or-adding-node-in-sql-server-cluster/.   See last section about possible and preferred owners and let me know if anything changes after applying recommendations in this section.